# php validation to check text field is not working

Tags: php, validation, isset

I am trying to create a simple tax calcualtor and need to validate the both textfields so they are not empty and it doesn't appear to be working any tips?

```
if(isset($_GET['taxSubmit'])) {
    $afterPrice = $_GET['taxPrice'];
    $taxRate = $_GET['taxRate'];

    $beforeTax = ($afterPrice * 100) / ($taxRate + 100);
if(!empty($_GET['taxPrice'.'taxRate'])){
    echo "<h1>Price before tax = &pound;".$beforeTax."<h1>";
} else {
    echo 'All Fields Required';
}
}
```

Somebody asked for the markup so here it is:

```
<form method="get" action="watWk5.php"> 
<fieldset>
    <legend>Without tax calculator</legend>
    <label for="">After Tax Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="taxPrice"/ value=<?php
        if(isset($_GET['taxPrice'])){
            echo $_GET['taxPrice']; 
        }
        ?>>
    <label for="">Tax Rate</label>
    <input type="text" name="taxRate"/ value=<?php
        if(isset($_GET['taxRate'])){
            echo $_GET['taxRate']; 
        }
        ?>>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="taxSubmit"/>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset" name="clrButton">Clear</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't appear to be working"? Show us your form markup too.

Comment: this `if(!empty($_GET['taxPrice'.'taxRate'])){` looks wrong. They should be separate `!empty()` checks not concatenated

Comment: just a second i'll update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable should have its own `!empty()` check

```
if(!empty($_GET['taxPrice']) && !empty($_GET['taxRate'])) {

   //proceed

} else {
//throw error

}
```

Comment: yes thank this is working will mark it correct when i can

Comment: my pleasure. ;)